# Chrome suddenly works very bad

Tags: internet, google-chrome, browser

I was using chrome for years without any problem, suddenly about a week ago some pages stop opening, sometime it takes minutes to load a page and sometimes it doesn't load any pages at all.

Temporally I'm using Firefox, but I’m so use to Chrome that I feel like switching from driving a ferrari to driving a bike.

What I've tried:

> cleaning all cache, cookies, installed extensions.
>
> reinstalling chrome
>
> mv ~/.config/google-chrome{,.bak}

Comment: Does `mv ~/.config/google-chrome{,.bak}` help?

Comment: @JosephR. nope, still the same

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if is there any broken/useless plugin which may cause the problem?

You can check the plugin list here (using chrome): chrome://plugins/

Just try disabling the plugins you don't use.

Anyway this may help: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/113910?hl=en

Comment: disabling plug-ins didn't help

Comment: Have you also tried disabling "Predict network"? (here: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/113910?hl=en )

Comment: yep, eventually i solved it by turning selinux on